# Android app revenue

Tags: android, admob, ads

I need some help. I am developing an android app (for revenue) so I want to know the following factors in detail:

1. Which is the best mobile advertising network that gives me the highest CPC (cost per click) rates?
2. What are the factors that affect CPC rates?
3. Is there any network which gives me fixed CPC rates?
4. Are there any networks that do not have any refresh rate (refresh ads on user action (click, swipe, etc))?
5. Is there a way through which I can calculate/get the exact earning of each click just after that click?
6. Same question for CPCV (cost per complete view(video ads) and CPM(cost per impression))!

I search a lot about these questions but didn't get/understand the answers... Can someone experienced please help me?!

Comment: I'm not sure about most of your questions, but Google AdMob is pretty great! It's manageable, easy to integrate, and best of all: It's Google!

Comment: but the biggest problem is that we are in dark until we recieve the payment because admob does not give any fixed/final info of our revenue until we recieve it

Comment: but why?does admob give info?what i search so far,i understand that admob uses very complex formula to calculate the cpm/cpc etc,as sometimes one click got lowest rate and sometime it got the heighest rate.....am i wrong? if so than correct me

Comment: Hi, this question does not follow the ["on topic"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidelines. Please refrain from asking questions calling for users opinions, and questions that actually contain 6 distinct questions that all require others to research on your behalf.

Comment: @raja I'm not going to argue about opinions, but I find AdMob simple, and easy to use and would recommend it to anyone looking around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your questions:

1. About 1M developers search for this answer - there is no one answer to that
2. How much the advertiser is willing to pay for this click (depending on Geos devices etc...)
3. There are, but you have to be pretty large for that. some networks guarantee cpm based on users location and velocity like [ogury](http://www.ogury.co/)
4. Each network support different refresh rate. refresh rate applies for banners and say how many time to fetch new ad. there are network which can be set to not  refresh like admob
5. You can look for example at the admob dashboard and calculate clicks by time filters. you can also use for example the [adsense - admob api](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/) for getting more accurate data
6. Again you can use the apis to get this data but it would be hard to calculate the exact click after it happens